# why groupby change the rows number

Tags: python, pandas

i have this code that i try to plot column x Ct and Fs based on Ft

so how can i solve this?

```
df = pd.read_csv('f.txt',sep=" ",names=list(["Ct", "Fs", "Ft"]))
df.iloc[:]




groups = df.groupby("Ft")
plt.subplots(figsize=(18,10))
for name, group in groups:

    plt.scatter( group.Ct,group.Fs, label=name,s=100)

plt.yticks(np.arange(0, 6,0.5))
plt.xticks(np.arange(0, 24,1))
plt.title('f',fontsize=20)
plt.xlabel('x',fontsize=20)
plt.ylabel('y',fontsize=20)

plt.legend(loc='upper center', ncol=3)
```

```
group.iloc[:]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are trying to make a scatter plot of Ct and Fs and want to have each point colored based on Ft I suggest using [Seaborn](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.scatterplot.html) or [Plotly](https://plotly.com/python-api-reference/generated/plotly.express.scatter). Matplotlib takes a bit more work to color by an object column.

No groupby needed.

After installing those libraries, here's how you do it.

```
import seaborn as sns
sns.scatterplot(data=df, x='Ct', y='Fs', hue='Ft')
```

or

```
import plotly.express as px

px.scatter(data=df, x='Ct', y='Fs', color='Ft')
```

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't automatically change the index names, that's the behavior of `groupby`, just reset the index then:

```
groups = groups.agg('first').reset_index(drop=True)
```

Comment: @MoniT Are you trying to get the first value, check my edit